# Quick Regex Question - Match between

Tags: regex

I hope there is someone who can help me with this regex

```
content.match(/<div class="content">.+#-#/ig);
```

I need to match everything between the `<div class="content">` [ Match everything inbetween ] up untill the #-# in the coding

I am using javascript

Thanks

Comment: Think you might need to edit this a bit, there are no square brackets in the regex so I'm not sure what you want to match against?

Comment: Can you give an example input, and what output you want for this input?

Comment: The classic "let's post HTML and hope that it doesn't disappear". I fixed it.

Comment: It is HTML I want to extract so I want it to start at <div class="content"> --- There is always just one reference for it then I have HTML inbetween, and at the end I insert this as an identifier #-# supposed to grab everything between div content ----- and #-# both should be unique

Comment: I think the problem might be line breaks ?

Comment: Is your HTML just a string or do you have access to its DOM?

Comment: Gumbo I am grabbing it as a string - making a static version of a dynamic site

Comment: what is the value of the javascript variable `content`?

Comment: Hi David - yes the variable is content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
/<div class="content">[\s\S]+?#-#/ig
```

`[\s\S]` will match any character including line breaks and the non-greedy quantifier `+?` will expand the match to the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Well, strictly speaking:

```
content.match(/<div class="content">(.+?)##/ig);
```

Result is every even element in the array. But you really shouldn't be using regexp for this. If you want the content of the 'content' div you should use DOM methods. Along the lines of:

```
function getContents () {
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV');
  var result = [];
  for (var i=0,l=divs.length;i<l;i++) {
    if (divs[i].className == 'content') {
        var content = divs[i].innerHTML;
        result.push(content.match(/(.*?)##/)[1]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the regex it is working 100% - I am trying the DOM example but get a 'document' is undefined error

Comment: Slebetman - How would I call the function ?
<body onload="function getContents()">

Comment: Call it where you would have called the content.match.

Comment: Finally I figured out why I am using REGEX and not the DOM object - My coding is in xhtml and the DOM in IE8 convert the text to HTML with the inner.html = the resulting code is a total mess! and it converts my xhtml to html